# Redrawing Matplotlib interactive plot with fixed background with Ktinter/PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, pysimplegui

I've searched all day and found a lot of solutions and can't apply anything on my problem, so I'm desperate enough now to ask you guys.
I just want a Interface were you can move a slider and this will change a plot accordingly. I've done it, but the problem is, that the whole diagramm gets replotted and this takes time and is ugly. I just want to update the plot itself, but the background with the axes etc. should stay the same.
I hope someone can help me.
My code is quite messy, since I tried to implement various solutions, but if you run it, you get the idea and the problem I have.

I've read to use blitting, but I just can't apply it with the FigureCanvasTkAgg, since I want it to be interactive and not a ongoing animation. My main problem is, that I need to deliver the figure and canvas to FigurCanvasTkAgg and can't get this together with the saving and restoring of the background.

```
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


_VARS = {'window': False,
         'fig_agg': False,
         'pltFig': False}

layout = [[sg.Canvas(key='figCanvas')],
          [sg.Button('Send message'), sg.Button('Bye!')],
          [sg.Slider(range=(0, 3000), default_value=1000,
          expand_x=True, enable_events=True,
          orientation='horizontal', key='-SL-')]]
_VARS['window'] = sg.Window('Such Window',
                            layout,
                            finalize=True,
                            resizable=True,
                            location=(100, 100),
                            element_justification="right")


x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.show(block=False)
plt.pause(0.1)
bg = fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(fig.bbox)
ax.plot(x, x)
fig.canvas.blit(fig.bbox)


calib_frame = tk.LabelFrame(_VARS['window']['figCanvas'].TKCanvas, text='probe angle calibration', padx=5, pady=5)
calib_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='ns')
calib_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=calib_frame)
calib_canvas.draw()
calib_canvas.blit(fig.bbox)
calib_canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(column=0, row=0)


def updateChart(Mon_Rueck):
    fig.canvas.restore_region(bg)
    fig.canvas.blit(fig.bbox)
    calib_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=calib_frame)
    ax.clear()
    ax.plot(x, np.sin(Mon_Rueck*x))
    calib_canvas.draw()
    calib_canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(column=0, row=0)

while True:
    event, values = _VARS['window'].read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Bye!':
        break
    if event == '-SL-':
        response = 'Monatliche Rücklagen: ' + str(values['-SL-'])
        updateChart(values['-SL-'])
_VARS['window'].close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I may have screwed up the axis values by making the change, but it's smoother.  The problem, best I could tell, only happened while the slider was being held down.

The change I made was to comment out the first 2 lines of `updateChart` so that it's not doing the restore and blit.

```py
def updateChart(Mon_Rueck):
    # fig.canvas.restore_region(bg)
    # fig.canvas.blit(fig.bbox)
    calib_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=calib_frame)
    ax.clear()
    ax.plot(x, np.sin(Mon_Rueck*x))
    calib_canvas.draw()
    calib_canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(column=0, row=0)
```

[image: PySimpleGUI capture]